# Retrieving data via POST request

Tags: post, python-3.x, urllib

I am having trouble obtaining data programmatically from a particular webpage.

http://www.uschess.org/msa/thin2.php allows one to search for US Chess ratings by name and state.

Submitting a POST request, I can get to the equivalent of http://www.uschess.org/msa/thin2.php?memln=nakamura&memfn=hikaru but still requires one to clicking the "Search" button to get useful data.  What is the best way to get to that results page?

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
data = {'memfn':'hikaru', 'memln':'nakamura'}
url = r'http://www.uschess.org/msa/thin2.php'
s = urllib.parse.urlopen(url, bytes(urllib.parse.urlencode(data),'UTF-8'))
s.read()
```

Thanks!

Comment: `urllib3` is an independent library for both python 2 and 3; the tag description is wrong (I'll correct it).

Comment: I know I'm not solving your particular code issue, but I highly recoomend http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ - It's seriously made for human beings. Give it a whirl, you won't live without it ever after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib

data = {'memfn':'hikaru', 'memln':'nakamura', 'mode':'Search'}
url = r'http://www.uschess.org/msa/thin2.php'
s = urllib.urlopen(url, bytes(urllib.urlencode(data)))
print s.read()
```

Basically you need to submit hidden parameter `mode` with value `Search` to imitate the button press.

Note: I rewrote it for python 2.x, sorry, but I didn't have python3 handy.

Comment: Thanks, perfect.  It is a little mysterious to me why this works (since the value of the mode parameter is already 'Search' on the page) but clearly this is the right thing to do.  I'll check out requests as well.

Comment: It works because you actually need to _submit_ it, it's on the page, but you're not forcing the value of it into the post request. post request emulates buttonpress, but if the value of button itself is ommited, php code behind it probably fails to notice that form was submitted.